# Fixed div with respect to container NOT body

Tags: css

I want to fix position of div with respect to it's container div, NOT with respect to body. I played a lot and searched as well but didn't find the solution.

Please not **.container** and **.content** both are of responsive height and can't take a fixed height. **height:2000px;** given to **.container** for demontration purposes only.

While the actual case is: **heights are responsive.** **[Here is jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FbSBP/)**

```
<div class="content">content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content
</div>
<div class="container">content
    <div class="loaderWrap">
        <div class="loader2">Loading Spinner</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    background:green;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    background:orange;
    height:2000px;
}
.loaderWrap {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: red
}
.loader2 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: `position: fixed` is always in relation to the viewport, but if you change it to `position: absolute` you'll position it in relation to its nearest positioned ancestor.

Comment: You mean something like this http://jsfiddle.net/FbSBP/2/ ?

Comment: Only .loader2 needs to be fixed WITHING .loaderWrap